# Where can I put my list?

Tags: c#

Currently I have this list:

```
List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
              {
                new Car()
                { 
                    CarId = 1, 
                    CarName = "BMW", 
                    CarMod = "M6",                   
                }, 
              }
```

Under Form1.cs. I want it in a class maybe called MyCars.cs and be able to call upon it with this linq which lies under Form1.cs.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string entered = txtBox.Text;

            var q = from car in cars
                        where car.CarMod.Contains(entered)
                        select cars;

            dataGridView1.DataSource = query.ToList();      
        }
```

How do I call on it without getting "The name cars dosent exist in the current context"?

Wouldn't it be better and more elegant to put it in a class? I was thinking of making a class called  MyCars.cs

Thanks alot for all help

Comment: Note: MyCars.cs is file and it can contain many classes. besides its is strange that you know lists, linq and don't know how to move class to different file :/

Comment: Show what MyCards.cs looks like then.

Comment: I want:

List<Car> cars = new List<Car>()
              {
                new Car()
                { 
                    CarId = 1, 
                    CarName = "BMW", 
                    CarMod = "M6",                   
                }, 
              }

in MyCars.cs. But i have problems calling upon it in Form1.cs because i get the error "The name cars dosent exist in the current context" in Form1.cs

Comment: Right click on Car (where you getting error), select Resolve and then using .... This will add using statement. I guess your Car class is in different namespace then Form1

Comment: I still get the error "The name cars dosent exist in the current context"

Ok Lemme explain again. I have 2 classes in a folder called Classes.
Cars.cs and Dummies.cs where cars contains the properties and Dummies.cs contains List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>() etc etc.
I use Form1.cs with btnSok_click to call on the list with Linq. Im also using "using MyFavCars.Classes" to fetch the classes... 
What do i do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, your goal is not to create a new class-type, but rather have your car logic in a separate file? You can put it in another file as long as the classname is the same. If the form is made in a 'normal' way, from .net 2.0 and up, they should be in a partial class

```
//Form1.cs
namespace A
{
   public partial class Form1
   {
       public Form1()
       {
           InitalizeComponent();
       }
   }
}
```

As long as you use both the same name space and a partial class in the other file, you're good to go

```
//MyCars.cs
namespace A
{
   partial class Form1
   {
       List<Car> cars = ..... /etc
   }
}
```

Comment: Like i told Tim, i just want i elsewhere than Form1.cs to keep that class as clean from code as possible.. To make my solution more elegant. :)

Comment: @Pota Uhm, yes, that's just what this solution should accomplish, the bottom logic representing the mycars.cs file. Unless you also want the initialization logic out of the type Form1? Having both a separation of physical file and of class? (you'd still have to declare your private variable inside the form1 class though)

Comment: I still get the error "The name cars dosent exist in the current context"

Ok Lemme explain again. I have 2 classes in a folder called Classes.
Cars.cs and Dummies.cs where cars contains the properties and Dummies.cs contains List<Actor> actors = new List<Actor>() etc etc.
I use Form1.cs with btnSok_click to call on the list with Linq. Im also using "using MyFavCars.Classes" to fetch the classes... 
What do i do wrong?